# Using str_replace for digit when grater than ten

Tags: php

Here is my code-

```
$input=10;
$number = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$text = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');
$print = str_replace($number, $text, $input);
```

what I'm expecting is replace '10' with 'k'. but its replacing 10 as 'ba'
How actually use str_replace in above condition?

Comment: Put "10" at begin of an array in $number, also you miss ' at the end of 10 in $number array. Edit: also you need to put 'k' in front.

Comment: Welcom to SO. Where is your code that you have tried to replace 10 with k?

Comment: @SoftGuide: Sorry. it was typo. Fixed that. Gonna try 10 on first as you said.

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace  Example #2

Comment: All given answer are not pointing to the **real** problem of your code! And this would be the function itself!

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123: I'll keep in mind in future :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input=10;
$number = array('10','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$text = array('k','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$print = str_replace($number, $text, $input);
```

It's enough to put '10' and 'k' at begin, so he first replace this string and not any other.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This method was most suitable for my project code. :-) I'm gonna take this answer as solution. :-)

Comment: @platform Just to let you know that this answer is just a dirty workaround and doesn't solve your real problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
    $input=10;
    $number = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
    $text = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');

    $key=array_search($input,$number);
    $number[$key]='k';
    print_r($number);
```

( or)

```
$number[$key]=$text[$key];
print_r($number);
```

output:

```
Array( 
        [0] => 0 
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 5
        [6] => 6 
        [7] => 7 
        [8] => 8 
        [9] => 9 
        [10] => k
     )
```